# How to place condition in node pipeline Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to place a condition in node for select an agent master or stage?

```
def curNode = "${env.Environment}"

node(curNode === 'prod' ? 'master' : 'stage') { <= "error this"
    try {
        dir(env.Environment) {
            stage("Clone repository") {
               echo "clong success"
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        echo 'Error occurred during build process!'
        echo e.toString()
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to compare two strings, you need to use `==`. When you use `===` it checked whether the objects are identical. Hence update your Script like the below.

```
def curNode = "${env.Environment}"

node(curNode == 'prod' ? 'master' : 'stage') { <= "error this"
    try {
        dir(env.Environment) {
            stage("Clone repository") {
               echo "clong success"
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        echo 'Error occurred during build process!'
        echo e.toString()
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. Thank u. I understood it 2 hours ago=)